# How to verify the message payload sent from Microsoft Teams in ASP.NET core?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I follow the sample code here [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook#code-example-c) to verify the request payload, but it does not work in my asp.net core project, looks like it is for traditional ASP.NET project. How to do it in asp.net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function couple months ago in an ASP.NET core project, you can take a look at the following code.

```
public TeamsAuthResponse Validate(HttpRequest request)
{
    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string messageContent = new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    var authenticationHeaderValue = request.Headers["Authorization"];

    if (authenticationHeaderValue.Count <= 0)
    {
        return new TeamsAuthResponse(false, "Authentication header not present on request.");
    }

    if (!authenticationHeaderValue[0].StartsWith("HMAC"))
    {
        return new TeamsAuthResponse(false, "Incorrect authorization header scheme.");
    }

    // Reject all empty messages
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageContent))
    {
        return new TeamsAuthResponse(false, "Unable to validate authentication header for messages with empty body.");
    }

    string providedHmacValue = authenticationHeaderValue[0].Substring("HMAC".Length).Trim();
    string calculatedHmacValue = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] serializedPayloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageContent);
        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_securityToken);
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSHA256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = hmacSHA256.ComputeHash(serializedPayloadBytes);
            calculatedHmacValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        if (string.Equals(providedHmacValue, calculatedHmacValue))
        {
            return new TeamsAuthResponse(true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format(
                "AuthHeaderValueMismatch. Expected:'{0}' Provided:'{1}'",
                calculatedHmacValue,
                providedHmacValue);
            return new TeamsAuthResponse(false, errorMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning(ex, "Exception occcured while verifying HMAC on the incoming request.");
        return new TeamsAuthResponse(false, "Exception thrown while verifying MAC on incoming request.");
    }
}
```